# How do I pass along SectionList's scrollToLocation to child components?

Tags: react-native, sections

I'm building a React Native app that has a process guide the user needs to fill out. When the user has selected an option, then I want to scroll him down the screen to where the new options appears.

To achieve that I need SectionList's [scrollToLocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html#scrolltolocation) function available in my button's onClick.

```
 42 const sectionData = [
 43   {
 44     data: [
 45       {
 46         key: "1",
 47         program:  [
 48           <Question
 49             key={1}
 50             onAnswerSubmit={() => {
 51               scrollToLocation(1);
       /* 
           How do I access scrollToLocation from 
           SectionList and pass it along as a prop here?
        */
 52             }}
 53           />,
 54           <Question
 55             key={2}
 56             onAnswerSubmit={() => {
 57               scrollToLocation(1);
 58             }}


130   public render() {
131
132     return (
133       <SectionList
135         sections={ sectionData }
136         renderItem={ renderItem }
137         renderSectionHeader={ sectionHeader }
138         keyExtractor={ keyExtractor }
139       >
140       </SectionList>
```

**Question.tsx**

```
 28   public render() {
 29     return (
 30       <Question
 31         {...this.props}
 32         onPress={this.props.onAnswerSubmit}
 33       />
 34     );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add ref to SectionList like this

```
ref = "foo"
```

and call it

```
this.refs.foo.scrollToLocation(params);
```

or

```
ref = {ref => this.sectionListRef = ref}
```

and call it

```
this.sectionListRef.scrollToLocation(params);
```